# Separating functions to a separate header that rely on another function not inside the header?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have several C scripts that will all have the same format(functions), but occasionally the actual code within a few functions.  I am trying to separate a function into an external header file, but the issue is this:

```
int FunctionImExtracting()
{
    //some code
    FunctionThatCannotBeExtractedButTheFunctionSignatureWillAlwaysRemainTheSame()
    //more code.
};
```

I have a feeling that function pointers will be my friend here, but I'm not sure how.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Your wording isn't 100% clear.  Do you really want to extract full function definitions, including the function bodies, into *.h files?   It happens but it's very unusual.  Why can't you extract the function you're calling in the same way?  Do you realize that #include just performs textual substitution?

Answer (score 1):

You don't (normally want to) put the function itself into a header -- you just want to put a declaration of the function in the header, so other files can include the header and be able to call that function:

```
//myfunc.h:
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
int FunctionImExtracting(void);
#define MY_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#endif


// myfunc.c:
#include "theirheader.h"
#include "myfunc.h"

int FunctionImExtracting() { 
  // as in question
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a header file with the declaration of `FunctionThatCannotBeExtractedButTheFunctionSignatureWillAlwaysRemainTheSame()`. Then in the file to which you are exporting, you'll need to include this header. And the actual definition of `FunctionThatCannotBeExtractedButTheFunctionSignatureWillAlwaysRemainTheSame()` can still be in the file from which you exported `FunctionImExtracting()`.

Did I get your problem right?